# Regex repetition

Tags: regex, repeat, quantifiers

I'm trying to perform a regex replacement. Therefor I defined the following expression:

```
    ^(?:9903[0]*([0-9]*)){20}$
```

This Expression should match to

```
    99030000000000000001
    99030000000000000011
    99030000000000000111
    99030000000000001111
    99031111111111111111
```

but not to

```
    9903111111111111111
```

In fact, the expression above does not work until I either use {1,20} as quantifier or remove it completely. But as I want to check the length of the whole string without knowing the length of [0]* nor the length of the variable, there's something wrong with my expression.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

D

Comment: `^(?:66){2}$`, length must be 4 not 2.

Comment: your example isn't very clear, can 9903 be followed by any digits?

Comment: What do want to match with `[0]*[0-9]*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your initial regex.

The `{}` part is applied to en **entire** part between brackets. So your current regex requires that this part:

```
(?:9903[0]*([0-9]*))
```

Is repeated 20 times in its entirety, which is not what you want.

Then this part:

```
[0]*([0-9]*)
```

Makes little sense, do you want to capture the number after `9903` without the leading zeros? Then require that the capture starts with a non-zero number. `[0]` is a character class with just one character, equivalent to just `0`.

Concluding, I would do it like so:

```
^9903(?=[0-9]{16}$)0*([1-9][0-9]*)$
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oT5xE9/2)

***Edit:*** I realized later that if it's required to match 99030000000000000000 (get 0 in your capture group) then you need this:

```
^9903(?=[0-9]{16}$)0*([0-9]+)$
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oT5xE9/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking previously the length of the string with a [lookahead](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=[0-9]{20}$)99030*[0-9]*
```

The lookahead `(?=...)` is a zero-width assertion that checks what follows in the string. Here it is checking there are exactly 20 digits before the end of the string.